# Can`t update xcode/ loading black screen on IPhone device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I`ve got 2 problems. The first one is that I want to update my Xcode to v. 5.1 but I am getting error   **We could not complete your request. There was an error in the App Store. Please try again later. (20)** . My MacBook is running on OS X MAVERICKS 10.9.2. And then, I put run my project on real device and Only one thing I got is black screen. I can not do anything on my iPhone for now. When I try to run project again I get error  **Could not launch “Appname”. Busy.**

Any ideas how to fix?
Thanks.

Comment: Already fixed prob with black screen. Just rebooted device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Rebooted device and XCode updated after some days automatically. I don`t know the reason but finally.